# Считывание всех изображений из папки

Tags: python, pil

Имеется необходимость поочередно считать все изображения из папки, с целью изменения размера через PIL, не хотелось бы переименовывать 3000 изображений в 1, 2, 3, ... .jpg , а потом через цикл строкой указывать путь, поэтому возник следующий вопрос: существуют ли какие-либо библиотеки для подобных нужд?

Comment: Так что нужно сделать-то? Найти все картинки в jpg, изменить их размер и сохранить?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно зделать через [BIMP](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26259), который сделан на базе [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) - прекрасная программа для обработки изображений. BIMP позволяет вызвать практически все функции GIMP в пакетном режиме.

Порывшись найдете массу примеров как писать, все очень просто - можно уменьшить размер, добавить водяные знаки, да все что угодно практически.